# Mentioning funding from previous research without direct influence on current paper?

Tags: publications, funding, acknowledgement

Consider the following situation: A student is at a university U, funded by a certain stipend, with the ambition of pursuing a phd in research area X. After a year he drops out because things are not working with the professor. Another year later he starts work on a paper in the research area X that is not based on work he did while at U. Would it be
a) necessary (I don't think so)
b) appropriate (neither)
c) possible (maybe)
to mention that previous funding in an acknowledgement of a publication?

Before you ask:

Why not ask the professor? - He's a difficult person.

Is it really not based on work at U? - X mainly is an application of Y the basics of which you learn during you bachelor's and master's and which is easily enough to develop the idea for the paper. No reference to notes taken or things learnt while at U, only benefit is some knowledge of the literature on X, helpful in preparing a final manuscript. Which I don't think usually warrants an acknowledgement, does it?

Comment: It is difficult to assess, because your second work in area X was not done by your completely virgin mind, you surely learned something during your first work on X at U.

Comment: the more I read your quesion, the more I think "only benefit is some knowledge of the literature on X, helpful in preparing a final manuscript." means the question is wrong and there is a *direct influence on current paper* (explicitly said: you saved time for your current study because you did the literature research previously)

Comment: You save time on your current work because you studied, because, say, you attended a lecture on differential geometry during you bachelor's. Do you see people acknowledging there mom and dad funding their studies in papers? No. In a thesis, yeah, but not in a journal article. It's not customary as far as I know. So somewhere there is a line you draw for previous things you learnt in relation to your current work. I think what's mentioned in the question is beyond that line, but would like to hear experienced folks' opinion on it. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I set the line in "I was paid or I was provided equivalent non-monetary support to perform some research". So bachelor's courses are not part.
People should acknowledge mum and dad, if they provide funds, it would make explicit how crappy are fundings for PhDs and co. But people are too tight up and too naive to admit that, they prefer to acknowledge the 100$ grant from NSF instead of the 5'000$ from mom and dad.

Comment: Ok, but say you learn something during your phd while being paid for your research. In you book, at which point of your career do you stop mentioning the phd funding, how many years later? As soon as you're at the next university/on the next grant, and the results you publish do not directly stem from your phd work, right?

Comment: as long as you already published something while being funded by X, the fundings X exhausted their scope.
Afterwards you cite the research funded by X, instead of acknowledging the fundings, you can cite the product of those fundings.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are two quite different sorts of funding. First, there is general funding of a person engaged in some scholarship endeavor. Scholarships and many fellowships are like that. They are independent of the details of what you work on.

The second sort of funding is specific to a project. Some government grants are like that. A person/team is going to pursue a particular line of enquiry and needs funding for equipment, or students, etc.

For the second sort of funding there is no need to acknowledge it on other unrelated projects. For the first kind it is courteous if not always necessary to acknowledge old funding. Current funding of the second kind should probably be acknowledged.

Given the circumstances you describe, I doubt that acknowledgement of the early funding or even the first university is needed, though it might be courteous to do so, especially if it was funding of the first sort described above. That funding helped get you to where you are - in a position to do the current research even if it didn't contribute directly to the project.

It is probably better, however, to err on the side of acknowledgement in edge cases. You lose nothing by being generous.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I consider making his research project look better than it is sort of a loss, given the experience I've had with him, but I think that might be worth accepting in being generous with acknowledgements.

Answer (score 0):

The situation is not clear, only you can assess how much work (even preparatory work) was done at U.

A note of caution: since you are working on the same area X, there is a non-zero risk that your previous advisor at U find some part of your new work as plagiarized, or influenced, or done while you were at U, or said advisor may even think you are using some work/ideas/etcetc from *them*.

You state that new work is not based on old work at U, but if you did not publish anything while at U, there is no external, independent way to say "OP worked on X in a different way while at U".

You are also admitting that you earned some state-of-art knowledge at U, that you will use that knowledge in the final manuscript, so I tend to think you should not only put the U funding in the acknowledgement, but also both the current and the **old** affiliation at U in your author details...

Comment: Since you states the professor is a difficult person, keep in mind this: the later a problem emerge, the worse their reaction. You may think about being away and out of reach when the problem emerges ... that is a bad strategy: it means that when the problem explodes. you are not anymore on the same boat of the professor, so the professor will torpedo you without any second thought because you are "on the other side" and said professor will not procide you any kind of defense or support, on the contrary.

Comment: You are quite right, it's better to deal with this instead of publishing and seeing what he thinks when he finds out a year later. Of course, I wrote to him, but his "assessment" was based on ignoring parts of my e-mail, seemingly assuming the work was partially performed at U, while not knowing what I have actually worked on. He thought his "input" should be mentioned - non-existent as concerns the current work. While having published a work with a phd student where my concrete input on the manuscript (not much, but existent) was not mentioned. Not that I care, but...

Comment: And the part about only me being able to access how much work at U went into the current one is the fun part. Unless the funding at U is mentioned somebody can always try to make me look bad, right?

Comment: unfortunately, if the other side is a difficult side, it is better to err a bit on the safe side, putting the funding in the acknowledgments. Regarding affiliations and co-authorship, it is up to you. Since your old advisor already thought his "non-existent input" should be mentioned, I tend to be pessimistic and I think you are at serious risk of being accused of having plagiarized his work in the near future. Discuss this risk with your current advisor and decide for a common strategy with the current advisor, you may need a lot of support even if you are wrongly accused.

Comment: I don't think the risk is too serious, but I wouldn't rule it out. So indeed, maybe better safe than sorry. I have no current advisor btw., among alternatives in academia two didn't work out, the rest I didn't fancy or I had enough for the moment. My current research is funded by my day-job at a software company... Thanks for your advice.